# div image slider goes to far left when clicking left arrow

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, viewport-units

I have a parent div which is `594vw` wide with 8 divs in it each `50vw` wide + 16 in total margins = `66vw`. I want to have arrows on both sides and if you click one of them it should slide to the left or right by 66vw. While the right arrow works perfectly fine and goes back at 594vw to point zero, I am still not able to make it for the left side, meaning:

If I click the left arrow on the first image (going +66vw) it should bounce back to 0vw whereas when I am on div 2-8, it should just go back in +=66vw steps.

How can I combine a click function with an if function?

I want to click a left arrow to return each 66vw to the previous image/div, but also if the parent divs "left" parameters surpass +66vw, I want it to return to the first image.

This alone works fine (without the div going back at +66vw just each 66vw step endlessly):
​

```
$( ".arrow_left" ).click(function(e) {
$("#instafeed").animate({ left: "+=66"+'vw' }, "slow" )});
```

But as soon as I add this code, it skips to point 0 every time no matter from which point I click the left arrow (so no matter if div 1, 2, 3 it all goes back to 0)

```
if($('#instafeed[style*="left: 66vw"]') ){
click = 1; 
$("#instafeed").animate({ left: "0"+'vw'  }, "slow" )}; });
```

I already tried CSS selectors and JavaScript with no success, and I really want to do this in `vw`, not in `px`. I have seen how to convert `px` to `vw`, but it doesn't work for me, plus its too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

From the OP in a comment:

> I actually solved it.
>
> Just used `offset().left` and set it > 0 then add the if condition and it works.
>
> ```
> var click = 1;
> $(".arrow_left").click(function(e) {
>     var widths = 66 * click;
>     $("#instafeed").first().animate({
>         "left": "+=66" + 'vw'
>     }, "slow").next().animate().end();
>     click++;
>     if ($('#instafeed').offset().left > 0) {
>         click = 1;
>         $("#instafeed").animate({
>             "left": "0" + 'vw'
>         }, "slow")
>     }
> });
> ```